# JavaScript Explaining behavior of function with 2 loop to make multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have written a function below with the expected return and actual return. I really appreciate if someone can help explain the behavior/logic.

Edit: I added an example to show why I'm confused. I wanted to understand why after the 2nd loop, the first element of outerArray has been changed when I have pushed the value in the 1st loop.

```
function makeArray(n, val) {
 let outerArray = [];
 let innerArray = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < n; y++) {
   innerArray.push(val);
  }
  outerArray.push(innerArray);
  console.log(outerArray[0]);
  console.log(outerArray[i]);
 }
  return outerArray;
}

console.log(makeArray(2,"x"));
// 1st outer loop -> outerArray[0] = outerArray[i = 0] = ["x", "x"]
// 2nd outer loop -> outerArray[0] = outerArray[i = 1] = ["x", "x", "x", "x"]
// Result -> [[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x]]
// Expected -> [[x,x],[x,x,x,x]]
```

Comment: your expectation is wrong.
[[x,x],[x,x,x,x]] can you explain why you expect this result

Comment: You need to explain your attempted algorithm a little better. why should `makeArray(2,"x")` produce `[[x,x],[x,x,x,x]]`? That seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: Javascript is a [synchronous language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_programming_language) (Wikipedia); every single line of code begins at the same time and finishes by itself. The result of your code could technically vary every time you ran it (depending on the hardware and software). Your code would work in an asynchronous language like Python.

Comment: My expectation is that after the first outer loop, [x,x] would be pushed to the outer array and it would remain so. My apologies if this seems arbitrary or nonsensical but I just wanted to understand the basic behind javascript better.

Comment: Hi Rojo, I'm a beginner so I don't understand the concept of synchronous vs asynchronous yet. If you don't mind, could you elaborate further?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a counter for the second loop
2. For loop works fine if you use <= n - 1
3. You need to increment or duplicate the counter into the first loop

```js
    function makeArray(n, val) {
      let outerArray = [];
      let innerArray = [];
      let _n = n; // 1

      for (let i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) { // 2
        innerArray = [];
        for (let y = 0; y <= _n - 1; y++) { // 2
          innerArray.push(val);
        }
        outerArray.push(innerArray);
        _n = _n * 2; // 3
      }
      return outerArray;
    }
    
    const arr = makeArray(2, "x");
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to help me. I would like ask if you can explain further about: 1. why reassign _n 2. what is the fundamental change you make.

Comment: _n is a dynamic length for the innerArray. in the first iteration _n=2, it results in ['x','x']. when _n is reasigned * 2 it will take effect to the next iteration. In the second iteration _n=4, it results in ['x','x', 'x','x']. Then you can adapt it to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript loop behaves like any other language loop.
The mistake was, you were inserting the same inner array inside the outer arrays, while they look at 'n' inner arrays, they are pointing to the same single inner array.

```js
 function makeArray(n, val) {
     let outerArray = [];
     let innerArray = [];
    
    // lets run from 1 for simplicity if n is 2 it will run twice
     for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      innerArray = [] // first we create new array every time
    //  for (let y = 0; y < n; y++) {  you are always running the inner look n tiles 
    for (let y = 1; y <= n * i; y++) { // where as you expect it to run i * n times eg 2 * 1, 2 * 2 etc
       innerArray.push(val);
      }
      outerArray.push(innerArray); // we are pushing new inner arrary every time due to innerArray = []
      console.log('innerArray', innerArray,'i: ', i); 
     }
     
      return outerArray;
    }

  console.log('restult: ',makeArray(2,"x"));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Not to repeat myself so I'm gonna refer to my comment above. My expectation is that after the first outer loop, [x,x] would be pushed to the outer array and it would remain so. My apologies if this seems arbitrary or nonsensical but I just wanted to understand the basic behind javascript better.

Comment: Can you tell us what do you expect when the input be makeArrat(3,"X")

Comment: Hi again. I expect it would be [[x,x,x],[x,x,x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]]. This is just how the logic in my head works out, it's not supposed to be correct or something like that.

Comment: I have added an example to show my confusion better. Thank you again for your time.